# Potential memory leak in Console App using Autofac

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, autofac

I'm using Autofac as the IoC container in a long running Console App with `IHostedService` to run as background service. This uses timer and every few mins it wakes up and runs certain business logic. As per the Autofac documentation, I have created a child lifetimeScope in the timer callback and creating all the instances of the objects in that childLifeTimeScope and running the business logic. Also wrapped the lifeTimeScope in the `using` statement. However, as the app continues to run it builds up the memory and finally crashes.

```
 await using (var childScope = _rootAutofacLifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope("childScope")
 {
    childScope.CurrentScopeEnding += ChildScope_CurrentScopeEnding;
    ....
 }
```

In the below screenshot, I took two snapshots, one before the application started processing and second one after the processing has finished. As you can see the number of objects have significantly increased. I have checked the `CurrentScopeEnding` and its getting called correctly but lots of objects are left in the memory and not disposed. Any pointers will be appreciated.

[image]

[image]